# R functions not working correctly on Linux (working well on windows)

Tags: r, linux, windows

I am trying to do the following:

```
subset_Portugal <- subset(data_frame, data_frame$iso_code == "PRT" & data_frame$date <= "2021-02-27" & data_frame$date >= "2020-04-01")
```

Works great on windows, but on Linux (a fresh install) I get the following error:

```
subset_Portugal <- subset(data_frame, data_frame$iso_code == "PRT" & data_frame$date <= "2021-02-27" & data_frame$date >= "2020-04-01")
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(data_frame$date, "2021-02-27") :
  ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(data_frame$date, "2020-04-01") :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Why is this happening on Linux? How may I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That (most likely) has *zero* to do with Linux as R is extra-portable but is (most likely) due to different R versions (R 3.* vs R 4.0.*) with the changed default for `factor` columns in `data.frame` objects.

A quick `data_frame$date <- as.Date(as.character(data_frame$date))` will likely help, you can also use my [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which also accounts for the possible `factor` type for you via `data_frame$date <- anytime::anydate(data_frame$date)`.